# Extrange behaviour on terminator split vertically shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, 18.10, terminator

I have used terminator since eight years. I love splitting my terminal in several layouts depending on the task I am doing.

I upgraded (install from scratch) to Ubuntu 18.10 and I installed terminator. Current package version is:

```
dpkg -l|grep terminator
ii  terminator              1.91-1        all          multiple GNOME terminals in one window
```

I don't have idea about what is happening. I suppose system key binding is in conflict with terminator, but I'm not sure.